# Triangular Pixelation Technique in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I want to be able to create the triangular pixelation effect depicted in the following image.

[image: The pixelation I am trying to achieve]

I've been successful with the technique detailed [here](http://photoshoptutorials.ws/photoshop-tutorials/special-effects/quick-tip-create-triangle-pixelation-effect-photoshop/)--and it's nice--but It is not quite the effect I am after.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a traingle using the custom shape available in photoshop
[image]
Duplicate it And Transform it Vertical
[image]

Create a Square Layer on the place of duplicated layer
[image]

Ctrl Select the duplicate layer and delete the square layer
[image]

Merge the custom layer and the newly formed layer and duplicate as much u needed to form like this
[image]

Bring the picture you needed to triangulate pixels to be applied.
[image]

Ctrl and select the triangles layer
[image]

select the image layer and duplicate it with the original image layer duplicated
[image]

now bring the original image layer behind and move the triangulate image layer to the right side And You get the Triangulated Pixels
[image]

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't occur to me before.  This was just the help I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: Pretty neat original technique